# Kibana : Error with inserting a json document which dont have time field?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I have a small wrapper function to insert the data into elastic

```
def elasticInsert(self):
    """
    """
    self.elastic_r = requests.get('http://192.168.150.94:9200')
    self.d = self.r1.json()
    print 'Inserting into elastic'
    es.index(index='t1' , doc_type='report' , id=self.md5 , body = self.d)
```

Now the problem iam facing is when i inserted the first record(which does not have a timefield)

I tried to create index in kibana and i entered the t1 in index name then no options populated in the time_field

[image]

After this step failed i tried to add `_timestamp` field to meta_data in the advanced settings field.Now this field got populated now problem is ...

I created the index but when i opened the Discovery Page there is an error which reads
[image]

Error Log here

Error Log here

```
Saved "field" parameter is now invalid. Please select a new field.

 OK
259s
Discover: "field" is a required parameter
```

Again iam telling that my json explicitly dont have any timefield which i can specify.I have inserted data into other index in that case it populated `@timestamp` field but it is not happening here

Any suggestion on how to fix this issue.Thanks

Comment: Simply uncheck the box "Index contains time-based events"

Comment: This worked,but i want to see how many records inserted at time

Comment: In my class i have a variable like this                                               `self.detection_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
` But this field is not there in the json which iam pushing to elasticsearch.